# How to scale a shape to meet a dynamic element?

Tags: adobe-indesign, typesetting, paragraph-styles, formatting

[image: Section heading example 1]

[image: Section heading example 2]

I have a PDF of a report which uses the above styles for section headings. I want to replicate these in InDesign. I am not sure how the original one was created.

The starting point for me seems to be creating a gradient and then somehow apply it to paragraph rules. Following is the progress I have made.

[image: Paragraph rules setting]
[image: Progress till now]

The issues are:
a) intended style is not exactly copied
b) I have used indentation in the rules, thus for a longer heading, the words and effect are overlapping.

Kindly suggest some ways to replicate this style. Thanks

Answer (score 18, accepted):

[image: LorenIpsum]

### Paragraph Style

There are two paragraph rules:

- **Above**: the dark color and column width
  [image: above]
- **Below**: white and text width
  [image]

At the end of the sentence there is an added character with a character style incorporated as a GREP style in the paragraph style.

- **GREP style**: the example use this character "•"

[image: grep style]

---

### Character Style

- **Strikethrough**: with the stripes gradient, the same height as the paragraph rules

[image: character style]

- **Advanced Character Formats**: widen the character horizontally so that the gradient occupies all the space between the end of the sentence and the background

[image]

---

### Gradient

[image: gradient options]

[image: gradient]

---

### Result

[image: end]

Comment: You sir, are a bona fide InDesign badarse!